# How to Send Verification Email through Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I'm trying to send email to new user so that they can verify their email address first but I'm receiving an exception Which says Authentication required but my credentials are totally correct.

```
Swift_TransportException

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 Authentication required
```

[image: Exception Error Details]

```
.Env file
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.elasticemail.com
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=aniket.************
MAIL_PASSWORD=b6762146-*******-*******-******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls


Mail.php

 'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.elasticemail.com'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'support@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('aniket.************'),

'password' => env('b6762146-********-*********'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

This is how I'm Sending Mail

```
namespace App\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Repositories\ActivationRepository;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Mail\Message;
public function __construct(ActivationRepository $activationRepo, Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->activationRepo = $activationRepo;
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}

public function sendActivationMail($user)
{
    if ($user->activated || !$this->shouldSend($user)) {
        return;
    }

    $token = $this->activationRepo->createActivation($user);

    $link = route('user.activate', $token);
    $message = sprintf('Activate account %s', $link, $link);

    $this->mailer->raw($message, function (Message $m) use ($user) {
        $m->to($user->email)->subject('Activation mail');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Authentication required = Authentication fails..

Make sure in your `.env` file (or if you use your `app.mail`) the `MAIL_USERNAME` is the sender of the email and that `MAIL_USERNAME` and `MAIL_PASSWORD` are valid.

> The `from` `address` in your `mail.php` should be the same as `MAIL_USERNAME`

Comment: I would also add that the OP shouldn't change the mail.php config as he clearly did.

Comment: yes he should leave this as it is :   'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

Comment: I have configured my domain to send email through elasticmail i have tried sending mail through gmail but no luck, so my email `from` should be my domain email e.g support@example.com

Answer (score 2):

In your .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=user@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

In your config/mail.php

```
 'from' => ['address' => 'user@gmail.com', 'name' => null],
```

That will do it! :-D

Make sure to turn this on [google lesser app](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)